# how delete these conflict errors / rust/ E0277, E0432, E0599

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, solana, solana-web3js

I am working with a course on coatings with the Solana Spotify Project and studying on YouTube. Please tell me the code produces such errors, but everything is written correctly and clearly. I don't know where I forgot.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult;
use anchor_spl::token::{self,Token};
use std::mem::size_of;

// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("11111111111111111111111111111111");

#[program]
mod spotify_clone {
    use super::*;
    pub fn accept_payment(ctx: Context<PayerContext>, data: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        let payer_wallet = &mut ctx.accounts.payer_wallet;
        payer_wallet.wallet = ctx.accounts.authority.key();

        let ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
            &ctx.accounts.authority.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.receiver.key(),
            100000000,
        );
        anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke(
            &ix, 
            &[
                ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.receiver.to_account_info(),
            ],
        )
        
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct PayerContext<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"payer".as_ref(), authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = size_of::<PayerAccount>() + 8,
        )]
    
    pub payer_wallet: Account<'info, PayerAccount>,
    //Specific param to object
    #[account(mut)]
    pub receiver: AccountInfo<'info>,

    //Specific param to object
    //Authority[this is signer who paid transaction fee]
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_programm: UncheckedAccount <'info>,

    //Token Programm
    #[account(constraint = token_program.key == &token::ID)]
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    

    //Clock to the Save Your Time
    pub clock: Sysvar<'info,Clock>,

    
}

#[account]
pub struct PayerAccount{
    pub wallet: Pubkey,
}
```

Error appears here. The main problem in the code i think is here:

```
pub payer_wallet: Account<'info, PayerAccount>,
```

Code of error E0277:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `PayerContext<'_>: anchor_lang::Accounts<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> /src/lib.rs:10:1
   |
10 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `anchor_lang::Accounts<'_>` is not implemented for `PayerContext<'_>`
   |
note: required by `anchor_lang::context::Context::<'a, 'b, 'c, 'info, T>::new`
```

Second error E0432:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate`
  --> /src/lib.rs:10:1
   |
10 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `__client_accounts_payer_context` in the crate root
   |
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Third error E0599:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `exit` found for struct `PayerContext` in the current scope
  --> /src/lib.rs:10:1
   |
10 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `PayerContext<'_>`
...
34 | pub struct PayerContext<'info> {
   | ------------------------------ method `exit` not found for this
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `exit`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `anchor_lang::AccountsExit`
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
#[derive(Accounts)] to PayerContext
```

Like this

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct PayerContext<'info> {}
```

Comment: Have an error:error: expected one of `!` or `::`, found `PayerContext`

Comment: details  #[derive(Accounts)] to PayerContext
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected one of `!` or `::`

Comment: @МихаилПетрухнов would be nice to see the entire code